# How do I merge two rows in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, merge, sql-update

I have a table which has multiple records. One record has a few data, other one has a few data and updated ones

| ID | Name | gender | birthday | address | salary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jhon | null | null | newyork | null |
| 2 | Jhon Deo | Male | 1980 | null | 5000 |

I used id 1 in another table as a foreign key so I need that. But id 2 has more updated data.

I want to merge both records as id 1 and remove 2

| ID | Name | gender | birthday | address | salary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jhon Deo | Male | 1980 | newyork | 5000 |

Comment: Why do you want `id = 1` if you want to prioritize `id = 2`?

Comment: What is the rule if more than one rows have non `NULL` values in a column, like `name`? What is the rule for the `id`s?

Comment: If more than one rows have non null I prefer updated one (id=2) and id is primary key

Comment: The whole thing makes zero sense. What if the inputs also have ID = 3, with Name = 'Jhon Bug' and different data in the other columns? How do you know that ID = 1 must be paired (and updated) with ID = 2, and not with ID = 3? I don't see how you can reasonably fix this kind of problem.

Comment: @mathgut I know my data. Project start with manuel data but we built an integration and some dublicate data came to my table. I want to use old record and I want to get new ones data. so i need to merge old and new. this is not zero sense. this is case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to clean up the extra record (ID 2) using these statements.  Just be sure to replace `your_table` in the statements below with your actual table name.

```sql
UPDATE your_table t1
   SET (name,
        gender,
        birthday,
        address,
        salary) =
           (SELECT nvl(t2.name, t1.name),
                   nvl(t2.gender, t1.gender),
                   nvl(t2.birthday, t1.birthday),
                   nvl(t2.address, t1.address),
                   nvl(t2.salary, t1.salary)
              FROM your_table t2
             WHERE t2.id = 2)
 WHERE t1.id = 1;

DELETE FROM your_table
      WHERE id = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prioritize the latest id:

```
select distinct
       last_value(name ignore nulls) over (order by id desc) as name,
       last_value(gender ignore nulls) over (order by id desc) as gender,
       last_value(birthday ignore nulls) over (order by id desc) as birthday,
       last_value(address ignore nulls) over (order by id desc) as address,
       last_value(salary ignore nulls) over (order by id desc) as salary
from t;
```

Comment: I dont want select query. I want to update id=1  and remove id=2